# Can't reference key/value pair in MongoDB document where the key is a number

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, key, discord.js

I set the key for a document in my database as a number. I want to reference the key to get the value however, it returns undefined no matter what I try.

```
for(let x = 0; x < channelList.length; x++) {
     var chanQuery = channelModel.findOne({channelID: channelList[x]}, "channelName", function(err, result) {
         if(err) {console.log(err)};
         return result;
     });
     var datQuery = userModel.findOne({userID: userList[i]}, function(err, result) {
         if(err) {console.log(err)};
         return result;
     });
     chanQuery.then(function(doc) {
         datQuery.then(function(doc2) {
              msgChannel.send(doc.channelName + ": " + doc2[channelList[x]];
    });
});
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/874Ko.png) is a screenshot of the document I am trying to access.

Comment: Can you show an example (screenshot) of a document from your database (and blur out any sensitive info if there is). It'll give us a better idea as to how to tackle your problem

Comment: I updated the post to include a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I needed to convert the document into json with .toJSON() in order to reference the key as a number.